# minimizing a multivariate, differentiable function using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize the following function with `scipy.optimize`:

[image]

whose gradient is this:

[image]

(for those who are interested, this is the likelihood function of a Bradley-Terry-Luce model for pairwise comparisons. Very closely linked to logistic regression.)

It is fairly clear that adding a constant to all the parameters does not change the value of the function. Hence, I let \theta_1 = 0. Here are the implementation the objective functions and the gradient in python (theta becomes `x` here):

```
def objective(x):
    x = np.insert(x, 0, 0.0)
    tiles = np.tile(x, (len(x), 1))
    combs = tiles.T - tiles
    exps = np.dstack((zeros, combs))
    return np.sum(cijs * scipy.misc.logsumexp(exps, axis=2))

def gradient(x):
    zeros = np.zeros(cijs.shape)
    x = np.insert(x, 0, 0.0)
    tiles = np.tile(x, (len(x), 1))
    combs = tiles - tiles.T
    one = 1.0 / (np.exp(combs) + 1)
    two = 1.0 / (np.exp(combs.T) + 1)
    mat = (cijs * one) + (cijs.T * two)
    grad = np.sum(mat, axis=0)
    return grad[1:]  # Don't return the first element
```

Here's an example of what `cijs` might look like:

```
[[ 0  5  1  4  6]
 [ 4  0  2  2  0]
 [ 6  4  0  9  3]
 [ 6  8  3  0  5]
 [10  7 11  4  0]]
```

This is the code I run to perform the minimization:

```
x0 = numpy.random.random(nb_items - 1)
# Let's try one algorithm...
xopt1 = scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs(objective, x0, fprime=gradient, disp=True)
# And another one...
xopt2 = scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(objective, x0, fprime=gradient, disp=True)
```

However, it always fails in the first iteration:

```
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 73.290610
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 38
         Gradient evaluations: 27
```

I can't figure out why it fails. The error gets displayed because of this line:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L853

So this "Wolfe line search" does not seem to succeed, but I have no idea how to proceed from here... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your gradient function is likely incorrect. Try verifying it against finite differences (e.g. using [scipy.optimize.check_grad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @pv. pointed out as a comment, I made a mistake in computing the gradient. First of all, the correct (mathematical) expression for the gradient of my objective function is:

[image]

(notice the minus sign.) Furthermore, my Python implementation was completely wrong, beyond the sign mistake. Here's my updated gradient:

```
def gradient(x):
    nb_comparisons = cijs + cijs.T
    x = np.insert(x, 0, 0.0)
    tiles = np.tile(x, (len(x), 1))
    combs = tiles - tiles.T
    probs = 1.0 / (np.exp(combs) + 1)
    mat = (nb_comparisons * probs) - cijs
    grad = np.sum(mat, axis=1)
    return grad[1:]  # Don't return the first element.
```

To debug it , I used:

- `scipy.optimize.check_grad`: showed that my gradient function was producing results very far away from an approximated (finite difference) gradient.
- `scipy.optimize.approx_fprime` to get an idea of the values should look like.
- a few hand-picked simple examples that could be analyzed by hand if needed, and a few Wolfram Alpha queries for sanity-checking.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can transform it into a (non-linear) **least-square** problem. In this way you have to define intervals for each of the `n` variables and the number of sample points for each variable in order to build the coefficients' matrix.

In this example I am using the same number of points and the same interval for all the variables:

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from numpy import exp, linspace, zeros, ones

n = 4
npts = 1000
xs = [linspace(0, 1, npts) for _ in range(n)]

c = ones(n**2)

a = zeros((n*npts, n**2))
def residual(c):
    a.fill(0)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(npts):
                a[i+k*n, i*n+j] = 1/(exp(xs[i][k] - xs[j][k]) + 1)
                a[i+k*n, j*n+i] = 1/(exp(xs[j][k] - xs[i][k]) + 1)

    return a.dot(c)

popt, pconv = leastsq(residual, x0=c)
print(popt.reshape(n, n))
#[[ -1.24886411   1.07854552  -2.67212118   1.86334625]
# [ -7.43330057   2.0935734   37.85989442   1.37005925]
# [ -3.51761322 -37.49627917  24.90538136  -4.23103535]
# [ 11.93000731   2.52750715 -14.84822686   1.38834225]]
```

---

EDIT: more details about the coefficients matrix built above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I see more or less what you mean, but I'd like to avoid least-squares fitting. My objective function is convex, so I see no reason why I shouldn't be able to minimize it directly.

Comment: @lum I see your point... anyway, this is a very robust solution in case you need it..