# SciPy multivariate optimization with summation bound

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am attempting to perform a multivariate optimization using `scipy.optimize.minimize` with a constraint, but the constraint is not on each individual variable; rather, it is on the summation of variables.

Here is the quadratic objective:

[image: objective]

where `A` is a symmetric `m` by `m` matrix (`m` is the dimensionality of the points `x` and `y`).

The derivative of this function is very nice; `A` vanishes completely, making the gradient a constant that I can precompute. This is the gradient:

[image: gradient]

Here's the Python code I'm using to perform the optimization:

```
retval = scipy.optimize.minimize(f, A.flatten(),
    args = (S, dAi.flatten(), A.shape[0]),
    jac = True, method = 'SLSQP')
```

where `A` is the matrix (flattened), `S` is the set containing pairs of points `x` and `y`, and `dAi` is the precomputed gradient matrix (also flattened). The objective function `f` looks like this:

```
def f(A, S, dfA, k):
    A = A.reshape((k, k))
    return [np.sum([np.dot(x - y, A).dot(x - y) for x, y in S]), dfA]
```

However, this implementation spins off into infinity and never completes. I haven't been able to specify the summation constraint anywhere because the optimization method expects either bounds or inequality constraints on *each* variable, rather than on an aggregation.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing? [This question seemed close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110507/scipy-optimization-matrix-operations) but never got a solution. [This question involves multivariate optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244816/minimizing-a-multivariate-differentiable-function-using-scipy-optimize) but was just an issue of an incorrect derivation, and [this question seems analogous to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218355/scipy-optimization-with-grouped-bounds) but involves Pandas, which I'm not using.